# SQLFetch crashes with MSSQL ODBC driver, when binding to SQL_C_NUEMRIC field with custom scale

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, odbc, decimal

So I have a table in mssql created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(ID bigint,Age int,Salary DECIMAL(17,7), DATA varbinary($var_len), Occupation varchar(200), TimeCol DATETIME)
```

Now I would like to run a query and bind SALARY field to an `SQL_C_NUMERIC` type. I have just edited the code taken from a [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/appendixes/retrieve-numeric-data-sql-numeric-struct-kb222831?view=sql-server-ver15#sql_numeric_struct-overview):

```
RETCODE retcode;
SQLHENV     henv = SQL_NULL_HENV;
SQLHDBC     hdbc1 = SQL_NULL_HDBC;
SQLHSTMT    hstmt1 = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
SQLHDESC    hdesc = NULL; 
SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT NumStr;
const std::string connectionString = "DSN=dsn_name;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
char out_connection_string[1024];
short out_connection_string_length = -1;
SQLINTEGER strlen1;
SQLINTEGER strlen2;
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, NULL, &henv);
retcode = SQLSetEnvAttr(henv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, henv, &hdbc1);
retcode = SQLDriverConnect(hdbc1, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)connectionString.c_str(), connectionString.size(),
    (SQLCHAR*)out_connection_string, 1024, &out_connection_string_length, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hdbc1, &hstmt1);

retcode = SQLExecDirect(hstmt1, (UCHAR *)"select '20031201143000' as t, SALARY as SYMBOL_NAME, AGE  from employee", SQL_NTS);

retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt1, 2, SQL_C_NUMERIC, &NumStr, 19, &strlen1);

retcode = SQLGetStmtAttr(hstmt1, SQL_ATTR_APP_ROW_DESC, &hdesc, 0, NULL);

// If I comment these 3 lines out, everything works
retcode = SQLSetDescField(hdesc, 2, SQL_DESC_TYPE, (VOID*)SQL_C_NUMERIC, 0);
retcode = SQLSetDescField(hdesc, 2, SQL_DESC_PRECISION, (VOID*)17, 0);
retcode = SQLSetDescField(hdesc, 2, SQL_DESC_SCALE, (VOID*)7, 0);

// If I comment this SQLBindCol there is no crash
SQLINTEGER id;
retcode = SQLBindCol(hstmt1, 3, SQL_C_SLONG, &id, 4, &strlen2);

memset(NumStr.val, 0, 16);

// Call SQLFetch to fetch the first record.

while((retcode = SQLFetch(hstmt1)) != SQL_NO_DATA)// crash!
{
....
```

`SQL_Fetch` crashes with an access violation. If I change the order of `AGE` and `SALARY` in the select statement, it works. If I comment out the setting of descriptor fields, it works. If I do not bind the `AGE` field it works. If I set `SQL_DESC_TYPE` to another type instead of `SQL_C_NUMERIC`, it works.

Am I doing something illegal, are there odbc constraints of which I am unaware or is it a Microsoft bug?

**UPDATE:** Adding some information:

OS version: Windows 7 Professional, 6.1

ODBC driver manager version: 6.01.7601.17514

ODBC driver version:
Name: SQL Server 
Version: 6.01.7601.17514
Date: 21.11.2010

MSSQL server version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP4) - 10.0.6000.29 (X64)   Sep  3 2014 04:11:34   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

My ODBC DSN and driver are 32-bit though

Comment: *SQL_Fetch crashes.* -- What exactly does "crashes" mean?  An assertion?  An SQL Error?  Please be more specific.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Access violation, the program exits.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have edited the post to include the information

Comment: With an issue like this, many details you've left out are important. What OS (name and version)? What ODBC driver manager (again, name and version)? I presume "MSSQL ODBC driver" means you're using a driver from Microsoft, in which case the version is needed. If you're actually using an ODBC Driver for MSSQL from another driver vendor, then the vendor name is also needed.

Comment: It looks like this is a data type error, please add the ODBC version. The following links may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqlbindparameter-function?view=sql-server-ver15#diagnostics ;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258457/what-datatype-should-i-bind-as-query-parameter-to-use-with-number15-column-in

Comment: I know that ODBC requires that when data type or its attributes are changed in the descriptor, the bound buffer pointer should be set to null in the driver. But I assume fetch shouldn't fail in that case. We just retrieve data using SQLGetData

Comment: @droebi binding to a char or varchar column wouldn't be very efficient. This will require converting to string once on the driver side and from string to my decimal type on the application side

Comment: @NellieDanielyan: Can you add the exact error message? (ex. SQLSTATE, whole error message...)

Comment: @droebi there is no error message. As I've mentioned in the question the program crashes with access violation.

Comment: "Access violation" usually comes with some other information. If you're not seeing it in an alert dialog, possibly as the dialog window title, you should enable ODBC Tracing, and provide the relevant segment of the log (typically 5-10 stanzas before and after the one that contains the "Access violation" text).

Comment: "Unhandled exception at 0x5473D0E2 (sqlsrv32.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000." This is all I see.

This will not be seen in the odbc trace log, ODBC trace log only contains API call information and error messages returned by the driver, but in this case driver crashes before any error is generated. Last entry in the trace is:
"ConsoleApplicat 20a0-534 ENTER SQLFetch 
  HSTMT               0x00195248"

So no return code for the SQLFetch as it crashed in the middle of execution.